# Gnuplot : How to set max number of data points for fit

Tags: gnuplot, curve-fitting

I'm using a gnuplot script that involves several fits, on large data samples. Thus fit has to scale up its max number of data points several times, and it prints on the output

```
Max. number of data points scaled up to: 3072
Max. number of data points scaled up to: 4608
Max. number of data points scaled up to: 6912
Max. number of data points scaled up to: 10368
Max. number of data points scaled up to: 15552
Max. number of data points scaled up to: 23328
```

I would like to avoid that since it makes noise among the useful others information printed on the output.

I used `set fit quiet`, it diseabled all fit output except this one !

So my question is : how to set manually the max number of data points for fit, in order to avoid these messages?

Comment: The way the data space in gnuplot is scaled has been changed now, this problem should no longer occur as of gnuplot 5.0pl4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the `fit` source code (which you can download from [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuplot/files/)), it appears there is **no** parameter you can set within gnuplot to change the `max. number of data points`.
The default value is `MAX_DATA 2028`.
If you compile your gnuplot from source, you can probably change that to a higher value.
The only parameters you can control from within gnuplot are those mentioned in [the gnuplot documentation](http://www.gnuplot.info/docs_4.2/gnuplot.html#x1-8300027).

Comment: Ok thanks! If I have time one of these days I could modify that…